# Format of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

When working with a complex number is $\sqrt3i$ the same thing as $i\sqrt3$?

I am currently practicing writing complex numbers in standard form.

The question I was given is: Does $5+\sqrt1i$ = $5+i\sqrt1$?  I think it is yes.

Comment: Multiplication is commutative in a field

Comment: Is the edit ok,or did you mean to put $\sqrt{(3)}$?

Comment: @NUG: The two products are the same, but $\sqrt{3}i$ carries some risk of being mis-read as $\sqrt{3i}$, while $i\sqrt{3}$ doesn't.

Comment: Mathematically, the expressions have the same value, because, as mentioned earlier, multiplication is commutative in a field. Typographically, I think the $i$-first convention is easier to read and clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication is commutative even within the complex set.

Hence

$$\sqrt{3}i = i\sqrt{3}$$

Hence yes, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Multiplication is commutative, meaning that $a \cdot b=b\cdot a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Therefore, we can apply this to your situation, and let $a=\sqrt{3}$ and $b=i$.

Similarly, you can do the same with the second example and let $a=\sqrt{1}$ and $b=i$.